# How to solve linux-firmware package upgrade problem?

Tags: 12.04, firmware

If I do an `apt-get upgrade` I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-firmware
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/23.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 347 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 234639 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace linux-firmware 1.79.1 (using .../linux-firmware_1.79.9_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement linux-firmware ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_1.79.9_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/lib/firmware/ar3k/ramps_0x31010000_40.dfu', which is also in package bt-dw1705-firmware 0.1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_1.79.9_all.deb
```

I work with a fresh installation of Ubuntu 12.04 and this was my first step after starting up the computer for the first time. What can I do to resolve this issue?

I'm working on a Dell laptop which comes with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this command on terminal,

```
 sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_1.79.9_all.deb
```

Comment: what does this actually do?

Comment: That does not actually solve the problem only ignores it.

Comment: see my updated answer..

Comment: let us discuss here http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11833/room-for-avinash-raj-and-whoever-wants-to-make-company

Answer (score 1):

Error:

```
trying to overwrite '/lib/firmware/ar3k/ramps_0x31010000_40.dfu', which is also in package bt-dw1705-firmware 0.1
```

To fix it:

1. Open Synaptic
2. Search for *bt-dw1705-firmware*
3. Uninstalled it
4. Update your software

Enjoy!